# Regex, ignore non letter characters at before capital letter

Tags: c#, regex

I need to make a Regex string which matches server address taken from a file. The address always start witha  capital letter. The lines in the file are in the form:

```
#   note: first entry will be initial default
London,   lonxx:33333
New York,   NyC:222222
~CloudLondon, Clon:55555
```

I want to make a regex which takes each line starting from the upper case letter so in the case of CloudLondon it should  match only "CloudLondon, Clon:55555" without the "~" .
I have the regex for the rest:

```
 ^[A-Z](?<Location>[\w\s]+)\s*,\s*(?<Server>\w+):(?<Port>\d+)$
```

but how can I ignore the characters at the beginning of the line until the first Capital letter?

Thanks to anybody who is going to answer.

Comment: Have you got some more examples? If you're just looking to ditch the `~`, TrimStart on the input may be simpler

Comment: The idea is making the file reading more robust, I have no more examples but any non letter character at the beginning is fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the anchor `^` and move the character class into the group Location.

```
\b(?<Location>[A-Z][\w\s]+)\s*,\s*(?<Server>\w+):(?<Port>\d+)$
```

See a [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%28%3f%3cLocation%3e%5bA-Z%5d%5b%5cw%5cs%5d%2b%29%5cs*%2c%5cs*%28%3f%3cServer%3e%5cw%2b%29%3a%28%3f%3cPort%3e%5cd%2b%29%5cr%3f%24&i=London%2c+++lonxx%3a33333%0d%0aNew+York%2c+++NyC%3a222222%0d%0a%7eCloudLondon%2c+Clon%3a55555&o=m) for the group values.

[image]

Comment: It has a problem. In this example: 
`#   note: first entry will be initial default

London,      loncorba:25000
Hong Kong, fichkapp02:25000`     

the regex will match starting from "first"

Comment: @Doraemon Should the matches not be like this? https://regex101.com/r/LNWniq/1

Comment: When I do the same on notepad++ it matches `first entry will be initial default
London,   lonxx:33333`

Comment: @Doraemon In notepad use `\b(?<Location>[A-Z][\w\h]+)\h*,\h*(?<Server>\w+):(?<Port>\d+)$` where `\h` matches horizontal whitespace characters instead of `\s` that also matches newlines.

Comment: You are so good. Thanks.

Comment: Is notepad++ operating in case insensitive mode? I agree with 4thbird's regex - `\b[A-Z]` should only match from **L**ondon onwards, and it shouldn't find a match on a line with no uppercase..